# Getting Error while upgrading from keycloak 3.2.1 to 4.5

Tags: keycloak

When I upgrade my keycloak version from 3.2.1 to 4.5, I get following exception. I don't get this if I go from 3.2.1 to keycloak 4.2.1. So, looks like something specific to keycloak 4.5.

> [[31m08:36:40,672 ERROR
>   [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) Change Set
>   META-INF/jpa-changelog-3.2.0.xml::3.2.0-fix-offline-sessions::hmlnarik
>   failed.  Error: liquibase.exception.CustomChangeException: Leave only
>   single offline session per user and client: Exception when updating
>   data from previous version [[0m08:36:40,682 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been
>   requested via an OS signal [[31m08:36:40,687 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52)
>   MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./auth:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./auth:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public
>   org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>           at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to
>   construct public
>   org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:162)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2676)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:361)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:274)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:86)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:119)
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:300)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:140)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:584)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:555)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)

Answer (score 1):

This error could pop-up if the [Jboss Transaction Timeout](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_03/Platform.11-1/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0406settingthetransactiontimeoutonjb01.html) has been reached. The 4.x upgrade migrates all the keycloak realms; it takes a lot of time if you got [a lot of realms](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-September/015640.html).

At default the Transaction Timeout is set to 5 minutes¹. To change the timeout, you need to add both the `jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout` and `coordinator-environment timeout` in the **standalone.xml** file.

To set the timeouts to 2 hours, add just after the `</extensions>` tag:

```
<system-properties>
   <property name="jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout" value="7200"/> 
</system-properties>
```

Secondly, search for the `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:4.0">` tag and add

```
<coordinator-environment default-timeout="7200"/>
```

tag as child.

---

¹ *It took approximately 1 hour to update my company's 106 realms*